# Is this way thread-safe?

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety

I had old network client program. I am trying to change it to multithreaded program.

Could you please tell me your opinion about thread-safety of the following **JobList**?

**Original process (thread1)**

```
//Initializing
bThread1Done = false;
bThread2Done = true

While (true)
{
…
If (bThread2Done) {
  bThread2Done = false;
  while (!JobList.empty())
  {
    JobList.pop_front();
    LocalJobList.push_back();
  }
  bThread1Done = true;
}
…
Process(LocalJobList);
}
```

**New background thread (thread 2)**

```
While (true)
{
…
Recv(sock);
If (bThread1Done) {
  bThread1Done = false;
  while (!RecvList.empty())
  {
    RecvList.pop_front();
    JobList.push_back();
  }
  bThread2Done = true;
}
}
```

Comment: Before you go any further:  _Why_ are you trying to "change it to multithreaded."  What does it matter to anyone whether it is multi-threaded or not?  That's an implementation detail.  What is it that you want the program to do differently?

Comment: While it recieving message or waiting message, Program stops refreshing UI parts. Original program implemented by blocking socket function. I will use boost::asio async_recv and async_write, and put io_service.run into individual thread. I suppose that there will be only 2 threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not thread safe....

Protect your shared structures with mutexes and semaphores so only one process will access it at any given time.

**Additional information**
Your code thread safety is dependent on the compilers implementation of assignments like `bThread2Done = true;` and test like `if (bThread2Done) {...` which depending on

1. the CPU architecture and
2. the compiler optimization

may or may not happen atomically -- Assignments like `a=b;` may not happen in one instruction or one cycle, so the other thread may read data which is not compactly written.

Compiler optimization may eliminate the actual test in `if (bThread2Done) {...` if it is able to figure out that the variable is never set within the loop... there are hint you can give to the compiler that the variable is set outside the code (volatile) which may be needed.

Furthermore you code is implementing what is known as a spin-loop, which means that the threads are going to make the CPU 100% busy if they are locked out, which is really bad for your system performance in general.

Comment: Then you think I'd better use lock that JobList block. I try to get thread-safety without lock. If there are no more threads except that two and two [while] block will be exact that position, I think It could be thread-safe.

Comment: @heon, I added a longer description to address your comment/question

Comment: It sounds like that's dangerous like double-checked locking pattern. Thank you for your detailed comment.

Answer (score 1):

If this pseudo code is actually C++, then NO - it's not thread safe.

For example, accessing a variable from two or more threads where one access modifies the variable is undefined behavior. You also invoke member functions for the same object in different threads which is likely not thread safe as well.

Comment: Thank you. :) I will think about locking the JobList.

Answer (score 0):

By synchronizing the object you can achieve this functionality.

go through : [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602493/thread-safety-in-java-class)

Comment: Your link is about java -- It looks like the code is C++-like

Comment: okay sorry for the c++ link but i tried to gave you idea of synchronization.